# pm2: how to switch multiple app declaration json inside docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pm2

In my Dockerfile, there is

```
CMD ["pm2", "start", "app.json"]
```

If I have two json files, app.prod.json and app.dev.json, how to switch them when running docker containers?

my app.json:

```
{
    'apps': [{
        'name'      : 'app1',
        'script'    : 'src/app.py',
        'instance'  : 2,
        'exec_mode' : 'fork',
        'args'      : ['-g', 'test'],
    },{
        'name'      : 'app2',
        'script'    : 'src/app.py',
        'instance'  : 2,
        'exec_mode' : 'fork',
        'args'      : ['-g', 'test'],
    }]
}
```

In fact, I need to switch the args in above json file when running docker containers. I know that it may be easy to do this in Node.js by setting NODE_ENV, but I am trying to run python scripts.

Any comments welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Whats the goal here? change as container is **running** or start a new container with different conf?

Comment: If you want to change the configuration upon creating a new container from the same image, you can use environment variables to determine which config file to read. The environment variable can be passed in with the `$ docker run` command. 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/env-environment-variables